# corrupted library after hard shutdown

Tags: filesystems, ext4

yesterday night my laptop executes a hard shutdown because my battery was out of charge. After the reboot `Xorg` hangs and the troubleshooting was pretty hard. A first file system check of my `ext4` partition yields no error. Further I began to check the related `logs` and found nothing irregular. Since i use `xdm` i eventually looked in `/var/log/xdm.log` where i found the following line, that i had overlooked several times before

```
/usr/bin/X: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libpciaccess.so.0: undefined symbol: gzopen64
```

Then i invoked

```
apt-get install --reinstall libpciaccess
```

and after a reboot everything was fine again.

I know that a hard shutdown can corrupt data because the disc cache can't be physically written anylonger. Since i have no deeper understanding of the file systems interna i wonder why `/usr/lib/libpciaccess.so.0` was harmed by the shutdown? Particularly given that the system only reads from a shared library so probably corruption is less likely to occur in those sectors where those are located.

Furthermore i would like to know which filesystems are more resistant to hard shutdowns and which are less.

Thanks for your time and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that much a question of the "right" filesystem, but how you use it and how you mount it.

In case of ext3 and ext4 you can use the **ro**, **sync**, **dirsync** options.

Filesystems with intent-write-log are normally better, if the metadata is being synced before the actual write.

In your case it might have been that the library-cache (/etc/ld.so.cache) was corrupted - a simple `ldconfig` might have fixed the problem.

Sometimes you need to force a full filesystem-check to find and correct errors. Sometimes you need a rescue boot via Netboot or CD/DVD (image) to do so.

`fsck -f -y ...` - write the output to a log-file for later review.

After that go through every file/directory that has been reported as buggy and look of the package is still ok (on rpm-based-systems: `rpm -V`) - Debian should have a comparable mechanism to determine which package a file belongs to and to verify the integrity of the package.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I already looked up the keywords you've mentioned and you bring me on the right track. By the way: i did a `ldconfig` without success.